# How to decorate querySelector/querySelectorAll in JS

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to get and evaluate websites. Inside the evaluation, I heavily use [querySelector(selector)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) and [querySelectorAll(selector)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp). As the website's HTML sometimes changes, I had to change the selectors or add new selectors for once in a while. Now I am not sure which selectors are still in use and which are code that no longer runs and can be removed.

I would like to decorate these methods and log the selectors that have been used inside the decorated functions. I guess this would be much better than adding all the log-handling inside the main code. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` in the `prototype` of the `HTMLElement` and `HTMLDocument` object. But you for sure need store/keep the original function so that you won't break the code.

You could do something like this:

```
(function() {
  function wrapQueryFunction(name) {
    [HTMLElement, HTMLDocument].forEach(function(obj) {
      //store the original function
      var origQueryFunction = obj.prototype[name];

      //replace the function with the own wrapper
      obj.prototype[name] = function(selector) {
        logSelector(this, selector);
        //call the original function and return the result
        return origQueryFunction.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    });


    function logSelector(elm, selector) {
      console.log('selector: ' + selector);
    }
  }

  wrapQueryFunction('querySelector');
  wrapQueryFunction('querySelectorAll');
}());
```